# Сравнить строку с массивом строк

Tags: javascript, массивы, строки

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как на JS сравнить строку с массивом строк, чтобы выводились все элементы массива, начинающиеся на заданную строку?

Или, если это нерационально, то как сравнить два массива со строками на предмет совпадения первых элементов?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

С помощью функции [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
let str = 'th',
    arr = ['this', 'one', 'thousand', 'other'];

console.info(arr.filter(s => s.indexOf(str) === 0));
```

Comment: Логику понял, спасибо большое!! Код в синтаксисе ES6 написан?

Comment: @Alex, что-то вроде того. Стрелочные функции уже хорошо поддерживаются, фильтр тоже, так что используйте на здоровье :)